# CSS — How to blur a SVG mask?

Tags: html, css, svg, clip-path

I tried without success to blur an SVG clip-path. I tried different solutions but none has worked. I am unsure if there is another solution apart from `filter`.

Pseudocode

- The SVG clip-path should reveal the text below
- The edges if the SVG should be blurred

Thank you in advance.

HTML

```css
    .wrapper {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .h1, blur {
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
    }
    
    .h1 {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      font-size: 4em;
      clip-path: url(#svgPath);
      background-color: blue;
    }
    
    .blur {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      font-size: 4em;
      color: blue;
      background-color: white;
      filter: blur(8px)
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
      <h1 class="blur">
        Our principles inform everything we do. Whether you're preparing content, designing an interface or developing an entire service, start by reading these.
      </h1>
      <h1 class="h1">
        Our principles inform everything we do. Whether you're preparing content, designing an interface or developing an entire service, start by reading these.
      </h1>
    </div>
    
    <svg id="googlesMain" height="0" width="0">
      <defs>
        <filter id="f1" x="0" y="0">
          <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="15" />
        </filter>
      </defs>
        <clipPath id="svgPath">
           <circle id="clipPath" cx="250" cy="250" r="250"/>
        </clipPath>
    </svg>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, here's a way to do it using a `radial-gradient()` as a `mask-image`.

```js
var h1 = document.getElementById('masked');

document.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseListen, false);

function mouseListen(e){ 
  setMaskPos(e.clientX,e.clientY);
}

function setMaskPos(x,y) {
  h1.setAttribute("style", "-webkit-mask-image: radial-gradient(circle at " + x + "px " + y + "px, black 0px, black 200px, transparent 250px)");
}

// Initialise the mask off screen
setMaskPos(-999,0);
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.h1, blur {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 4em;
  background-color: white;
}

.blur {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 4em;
  background-color: white;
  filter: blur(8px)
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1 class="blur">
    Our principles inform everything we do. Whether you're preparing content, designing an interface or developing an entire service, start by reading these.
  </h1>
  <h1 id="masked" class="h1">
    Our principles inform everything we do. Whether you're preparing content, designing an interface or developing an entire service, start by reading these.
  </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Paul, thank you. This exactly what I was trying to achieve. Good to know I can't blur clip-paths.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `<mask>` rather than a `<clipPath>`. Clip paths cannot be blurred, but the elements in a `<mask>` can.

This following will work in Firefox, but is broken in other browsers:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}
    
.h1, .blur {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
    
.h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 4em;
  -webkit-mask: url(#svgPath);
  mask: url(#svgPath);
  background-color: blue;
}
    
.blur {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 4em;
  color: blue;
  background-color: white;
  filter: blur(8px)
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1 class="blur">
    Our principles inform everything we do. Whether you're preparing content, designing an interface or developing an entire service, start by reading these.
  </h1>
  <h1 class="h1">
    Our principles inform everything we do. Whether you're preparing content, designing an interface or developing an entire service, start by reading these.
  </h1>
</div>
    
<svg id="googlesMain" height="0" width="0">
  <defs>
    <filter id="f1" x="0" y="0">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="15" />
    </filter>
    <mask id="svgPath">
      <circle id="clipPath" cx="250" cy="250" r="250" fill="white" filter="url(#f1)"/>
    </mask>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

To make it work in other browsers, try turning it into a standalone SVG. Then use the `mask-image` CSS rule instead.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <filter id="f1" x="0" y="0">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="15" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <circle cx="250" cy="250" r="250" fill="white" filter="url(#f1)" />
</svg>
```

with CSS:

```
.h1 {
  ...
  -webkit-mask-image: url(mask.svg);
  mask-image: url(mask.svg);
  ...
}
```

Comment: I am going to try that. Is there another of doing this without having an actual SVG standalone that is compatible with other browsers?

Comment: Yes. You can move the text into the SVG. That way you avoid the issues with poor (non-Firefox) browser support for using SVG masks on HTML content.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, the edges of the SVG path are still sharp. I am trying to blur the edges of the clip-path without success.

Comment: Maybe its because I am using clipPath. I need this layer to move the mask with the cursor — https://codepen.io/diegooriani/pen/VqYOmg

Comment: You cannot use `clipPath`. Clipping paths are always sharp.  There is no way to blur a clipping path.